# Encrypting/Decrypting MPEG-2 Transport Stream in realtime

Tags: encryption, streaming, video-streaming

I have to send unicast mpeg2ts stream from one datacenter to another (dc1 to dc2). The output I get from encoder bank in dc1 is not encrypted and I need to encrypt it before sending it to dc2. At dc2 I need to decrypt it and send it to transcoders.

What would be a good way to do it? Would I see any additonal latency introduces, what would be a good way to minimize it?

Answer (score 1):

you could take tsdecrypt and modify that. We use it for realtime decoding and its fast

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand it correctly that you're talking about encryption/decryption here, not encoding/decoding ? As in "I want to secure the data vs snooping", not "I want to compress it in transit" ?

If so, the ideal way to handle that is at the transport level: setup a VPN between your two datacenters and make sure your VPN gateways have enough CPU and RAM to handle the flow. Typically, that will not add any noticeable latency to the transfer (as long as we're talking about human viewing it) if you have enough resources.